# Как создать в билде отдельную папку?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Объясняю ситуацию, делаю ритм игру , в игре например 5 карт ,тобишь 5 папок с музыкой,бэкграундом,текстом песни,таймингами для карты должно выглядеть примерно так:

Папка с картами\Карта_1\(и тут файлы) музыка.mp3,текст.txt,бэкграунд.png

И уже из этой папки Карта_1 я в юнити считываю музыку текст картинку на фон.
Если в едиторе я могу всё это загружать в Resources ,то в билде мне нужно как то создать отдельную папку и туда например загрузить по шаблону свои карты для прохождения.

Если не сложно хотелось бы попросить, узнать как вообще например мне обращаться в коде к этой папке если получить всё таки её создать в билде,что бы оттуда инфу брать.

У всех же разные пути на компе.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если речь только о Windows, то [`Application.dataPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-dataPath.html) может помочь.

```
string rootPath = Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "..");
```

Дальше можно создать папку как на вашем скриншоте.

```
string mapsPath = Path.Combine(rootPath, "UserMaps");
Directory.CreateDirectory(mapsPath);
```

И так далее по образу и подобию можно создать нужное дерево каталогов.

Либо в качестве папки для записи данных на любой платформе, рекомендуют использовать [`Application.persistentDataPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html), она как раз и предназначена для сохранения данных.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос не только `Как?`, но и `Где?`.

---

Касаемо `Где?`, поскольку в разных OS, разные права доступа, которые ограничены и имеются директории, предназначенные для хранения данных.

- `Windows`: `C:/Users/<UserName>/AppData/LocalLow/<AppName>`
- `Adroid`: `<Storage>/Android/Data/<AppIdentifire>/files`
- ...

Для этого в `Unity3D` есть [Application.persistentDataPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html).

---

А на тему `Как?`, поможет `C#`, позволяющий создать / удалить / проверить существование [папки](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23%20create%20directory) или [файла](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23%20create%20file).

Однако например в `Android` всё строже, за рамками отведённого места без полученного от пользователя разрешения на чтение / запись, не сунешься. Для скачивания и загрузки файлов, нужно использовать [DownloadHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.DownloadHandler.html) и [UploadHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UploadHandler.html), но проверить существование, можно с помощью всё того-же `File.Exists(path)`.